# C++ dynamically sized static array puzzler

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, static

While trying to explain to someone why a C++ static array could not by dynamically sized, I found gcc disagreeing with me.  How does the following code even compile, given that the dimension **argc** of **array** is not known at compile time?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int array[argc];
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) array[i] = argv[i][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) std::cout << i << ": " << char(array[i]) << std::endl;
    //for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { std::cout << i << " "; std::cout.flush(); array[i] = 0; }
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this with gcc 4.2.1, and specified -Wall, without getting so much as a dirty look from the compiler.  If I uncomment the last loop, I get a segfault when I assign to **array[53]**.

I had previously placed guard arrays before and after the declaration of **array**, and had filled them with zeros, certain that the program must be trashing part of its stack, but gcc reordered the variables on the stack, such that I was unable to observe any data corruption.

Obviously I am not trying to get this code to "work."  I'm just trying to understand why gcc even thinks it can compile the code.  Any hints or explanations would be much appreciated.

*Update:  Thanks to all for your helpful and ridiculously fast responses!*

Comment: allowed by c99 I think: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/770297-c99-dynamic-array

Comment: The other basic problem is that you're using one compiler to test whether something is possible in a language.  You can specify a standard in gcc, and you can ask for strict conformance to the standard (`-pedantic`?), but you haven't, and therefore you're allowing compiler extensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variable-length arrays (VLAs) are part of C99 and have been supported by gcc for a long time:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Note that the use of VLAs in C90 and C++ code is non-standard, but is supported by gcc as an extension.

Answer (score 6):

That's a [Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which is part of the C99 standard. It isn't part of C++ though.

You can also use the `alloca` function, which also isn't standard C++, but is widely supported:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* array = (int*) alloca( argc * sizeof(int) );
    array[0] = 123;
    // array automatically deallocated here. Don't call free(array)!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These are called variable-length arrays (available since C99) and can be declared only as an automatic variable – try putting `static` in front and the compiler will reject it. It just involves incrementing the stack pointer with a variable rather than with a constant offset, not more than that.

Before the introduction of variable-length arrays, allocation of variable-sized objects on the stack was done with the `alloca` function.

Answer (score 2):

Variable-sized stack-based arrays are a G++ extension and perfectly legitimate there. They are, however, not Standard. Stack-based arrays can indeed be variably-sized on most implementations, but the Standard does not mandate this.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ cannot be sized except by using a constant expression. Arrays sized via a non-const are either part of C99 or a horrible extension foisted on us by GCC. You can get rid of most of the GCC crap by using the `-pedantic` flag when you compile C++ code.

Comment: Why do you think it's a horrible feature? It allows you to use the available stack space more efficiently by allocating just as much space as you need.

Comment: @Blagovest Um, you mean like using normal stack based arrays does? It is crap, and many in the C community (and *everyone* in the C++ community) thinks so. Also, it will *never* be part of C++, so it's a portability issue.